# How to enter in to network namespace and read the file content using C program

Tags: c, linux, linux-namespaces

In my Linux machine, i have configured the network namespace. With shell script or command line or system command I was able to fetch the file content present in the network namespace.

```
ip netns exec test_namespace cat /var/test_namespace/route.conf
```

Output:

```
cardIP=10.12.13.1
```

In a C program, I can use `system("ip netns exec test_namespace cat /var/test_namespace/route.conf")` command to get the output. But I prefer not to use this option.

Looking for an alternative method, I am not sure about the system call setns, how to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the manpage for setns, it looks clear to me. What have you tried anyway, and where did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're alergic to `system`, you can use [`popen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to read the script output as a file:

---

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* the command to execute */
FILE *f = popen("ls", "r");

/* Here, we should test that f is not NULL */
printf("result of `ls`:\n");

/* read process result */
char buffer[256];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f))
{
    puts(buffer);
}

/* and close the process */
pclose(f);
```